# How to convert NSString encoding to UTF8

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have done something like:

```
NSData *dt = [mystr dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];

NSString *str = [NSString alloc] initWithData:dt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then `NSLog(@"%@", str);`

However, if 'mystr' is English then the `NSLog` would print it as is, but if `mystr` is Arabic (for ex.) `NSLog` will not print anything, so how can I change the encoding of `mystr` to UTF8?

Answer (score 4):

Your first line creates some data that is in cp1251 encoding. Your second line says "read this data into a string, assuming that the bytes represent a UTF8 encoded string". But because the bytes represent a cp1251 encoded string, that's not likely to work very well.

NSString represents an ordered collection of characters. Internally it uses some encoding to store these characters in memory, but its interface provides an encoding-independent access to the string and you can therefore consider NSString to be encoding-agnostic. If what you want is a collection of bytes that represent the string in UTF8 encoding, then you don't want an NSString. You want to get an NSString to emit such a collection of bytes, perhaps using the -dataUsingEncoding: method you've already found.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
  NSString *s = @"Some string";
  const char *c = [s UTF8String];
```

Comment: gives syntax error: Array initializer must be an  initializer or string literal

Answer (score 1):

import

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h" and
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.m" files
```

after that where u r doing encode write in .h file this method

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```

after that write in .m file method implementation

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding 
{
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)self,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));
}
```

after that use like this

```
NSString *keyword=@"sample text";
```

here pass ur string whatever

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[keyword urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `[mystr UTF8String]` ? This returns a char *

Comment: whenever I do  NSLog(@"%@", [mystr UTF8String]); it crashes the app

Comment: That is because [mystr UTF8String] does not return an NSObject, it returns a char *.

Comment: use NSLog(@"%s", [mystr UTF8String])

Comment: I tried NSLog("%c", [mystr UTF8String]); it displayed unreadable characters

Comment: mystr contain this arabic word: تجريب

Answer (score -2):

You can try this 
1)  NSString to NSData(NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding

```
NSString *text=@"This is Sample Text Conversion.....";

NSData *data=[text dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
```

2)Revers  process.

```
NSString *textRev=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@" Actual String.. %@",textRev);
```